# Generate Sonar Report from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a C# Solution and we want to build SonarQube report directly from VisualStudio code instead of sonar server. is there any way to export sonar report from VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full SonarQube analysis results can only be obtained directly, or indirectly from a SonarQube server.  This seems like an obvious point, but you seem to want a different answer.

You can get limited results along the lines of what SonarQube provides by using SonarLint, which has a VS plugin: https://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio .